# Python Outputs for Lists

Tags: python

Why the output for the below prog is `[6.2202, 'aboy', False, 87]` and not `[6.2202, 'aboy', False, 641]`

```py
L=[2e-04, 'a', False, 87]
T=[6.22, 'boy', True, 554]
for i in range(len(L)):
 if L[i]:
    L[i] = L[i] + T[i]
 else:
    T[i] = L[i] + T[i]
    break
print(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `break` statement in the `else` clause causes the loop to stop,
so after the first time the condition is false - no following iterations will happen

(Of course for `i==2` you get `L[i] == False` so you enter the `else` clause and the loop never executes for `i==3` with the values `87` and `554`)

Comment: Thanks a lot.Understood